# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am following this tutorial in order to **scrape** real time data. Link: https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-multiple-amazon-stores-with-python-5eab811453a8
However, I have the following error. "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'url'"

```
    import requests
from glob import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

# http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/common-user-agent-list/
HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

# imports a csv file with the url's to scrape
prod_tracker = pd.read_csv('TRACKER_PRODUCTS.csv', sep=';')
prod_tracker_URLS = prod_tracker.url

# fetch the url
page = requests.get(prod_tracker_URLS[0], headers=HEADERS)

# create the object that will contain all the info in the url
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
```

Comment: `prod_tracker` is a pandas DF - it has no property `url`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if prod_tracker_URLS is having any URL(s) or not.

page = requests.get(prod_tracker_URLS[0], headers=HEADERS)
is giving the expected output if you hardcode any URL.

The only issue seems like you are not getting any URL in your variable prod_tracker_URLS. Check whether you are using the right delimeter.